# Draw chart of sum combinations of numbers from a dictionary

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Given a dictionary as below,

`dict1 = {l: 12, b: 20, k:1, a:10, d:30 }`

Wanted to draw charts are which represent the sum of each possible combination of the numbers in the dictionary. Chart representation of the one possible combination would be as below.

[image]

The combinations are ordered in the descending order of the sum. Within the combination, the element are shown in the descending order of the value.

I need some help to go about this in a Jupyter notebook with `matplotlib` or `seaborn` or similar libraries.

Comment: Do you have problems with the algorithm or the visualisation?

Comment: The problem is with the visualization

Comment: How do you determine which numbers are combined and which are not?

Comment: It’s all “possible” combinations .. and one chart per combination

Comment: @user3206440 If you're still interested in a solution, could you perhaps give an update to my answer below, as to which option you're looking for (see comments)?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure whether I caught all eventualities, but here's my **updated** attempt, which collects all possible combinations.
If you want to have more whitespace between labels, you'd need to either increase the `figsize` or decrease the `fontsize` (or decide on when and how to "break" the continuous "number line" along x).

**Result:**

[image: A flowchart-like number line in matplotlib]

**Code:**

```py
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

input_dict= {'l': 12, 'b': 20, 'k':1, 'a':10, 'd':30 }

combinations=[]
## set the length of calculated combinations here:
for lengths in range(1,len(input_dict)):
    perm_length=lengths
    combinations += list(map( dict, itertools.combinations( input_dict.items(), perm_length  ) )  )

sum_dict={}
for d in combinations:
    s=sorted(d,key=d.get,reverse=True)
    sum_dict[sum(d.values())]=list(s)
ordered_dict={x:sum_dict[x] for x in sorted(sum_dict, reverse=True )}

## plotting
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
arrow_props = dict(fc='k', ec='k', 
                    headlength=10, headwidth=3, 
                    width=.5,shrink=0.15,zorder=2)

## make some nice colors:
cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('nipy_spectral')
norm=mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0,vmax=len(ordered_dict))


for i,a_sum in enumerate(ordered_dict.items()):
    ### iterate over the "addends", plot them at y=1:
    for ie,elem in enumerate(a_sum[1]):
        perm_length=len(a_sum[1])

        _txt='{0} ({1})'.format( elem, input_dict[elem])

        ## I create a ax.text() and ax.annotate() separately, 
        #  in order to have more granular control of the appearance
        _offset=-(perm_length-1)/(2*perm_length)
        ax.text(i + ie/perm_length +_offset , 1 , _txt, 
                ha="center",va="bottom",rotation=90, fontsize=8,
                bbox=dict(facecolor=cmap(norm(i)), alpha=0.5))

        ax.annotate("", xy=(i,0), xytext=(i + ie/perm_length +_offset, 1 ), 
                    ha='center',arrowprops=arrow_props)

    ## plot the sum at y=0    
    ax.text(i,0,a_sum[0],
            ha="center",va="center",rotation=90, fontsize=8,
            bbox=dict(facecolor=cmap(norm(i)), alpha=0.5))

ax.set_xlim(-1,len(ordered_dict)+1)
ax.set_ylim(-1,2)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: All good, except that the combinations with single elements or rather other than 3 is missing. The question was to plot all such combinations including single or multiple elements. Also a separator whitespace between the combinations would be nice

Comment: @user3206440 Sorry, but this wasn't clear to me from your question. Nevertheless, I've updated my code to include all permutations. Note that "more whitespace" can only be fixed by (a) reduzing fontsize (b) increasing figure size (c) zooming in (d) potentially removing the colourful `bbox` containers

Comment: Was looking for one chart per “possible” combinations.  What is included in the original post is one combination possible. Another one could be { d+k -> 31, l+a -> 22, b -> 20 } and so on ..

Comment: @user3206440 I'm sorry, I don't understand this last comment at all. Are you looking for (a) 25 individual plots (i.e. one plot per combination, one plot per figure) (b) separate plots for combinations of certain length (i.e one plot where all 5 elements are summed, one plot for all combinations of length 4, and so on) ?

Comment: … or (c) each plot should contain `{l: 12, b: 20, k:1, a:10, d:30 }` *exactly once*, and then you want to have various sum fields and pointing arrows (i.e. for length 4 you would get 4 *separate figures* where in each plot there is *one of the dict items* which is *not summed* while all others are summed into one)?